# Java regular expression: finding match errors

Tags: java, regex

I want to know the exact position of an error when a regular expression match has failed. But I couldn't find any class or method in Matcher neither in Pattern that can do that. Any help?

```java
Pattern regExpPattern = Pattern.compile("My regular expression");
Matcher matcher = regExpPattern.matcher("Input string");
if (!matcher.matches()) {
    // Better error handling here
    throw new Exception("Invalid expression");
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a working code excerpt:

```
public class FOPRequestParser {

private static Pattern regExpPattern;
private static String requestRegexp;
private static String regexpSeparators;

private static String[] INPUT_FORMATS = new String[] {"FO", "IFP"};
private static String[] OUTPUT_FORMATS = new String[] {"PDF", "PS", "AFP", "IFP"};

static {
    regexpSeparators = new String("(\\Q|@|\\E|=)");

    requestRegexp = new String("run" + regexpSeparators + "[a-zA-Z]+.*"
            + regexpSeparators + "inputFormat=(");
    for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_FORMATS.length; ++i) {
        requestRegexp += INPUT_FORMATS[i];
        if (i != INPUT_FORMATS.length - 1) {
            requestRegexp += "|";
        }
    }
    requestRegexp += ")" + regexpSeparators + "[a-zA-Z]+.*"
            + regexpSeparators + "outputFormat=(";
    for (int i = 0; i < OUTPUT_FORMATS.length; ++i) {
        requestRegexp += OUTPUT_FORMATS[i];
        if (i != OUTPUT_FORMATS.length - 1) {
            requestRegexp += "|";
        }
    }
    requestRegexp += ")";
}


public FOPRequestParser() {
    regExpPattern = Pattern.compile(requestRegexp);
}

public void processRequest(String request) throws Exception {
    Matcher matcher = regExpPattern.matcher(request);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid expression");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FOPRequestParser conversion = new FOPRequestParser();
    try {
        String exp1 = new String("run|@|" +
                "c:\\input_file.fo|@|" +
                "inputFormat=FO|@|" +
                "c:\\output_file.pdf|@|" +
                "outputFormat=PDF");
        conversion.processRequest(exp1);
        System.out.println("Valid expression");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you give an example of input to the string and regex that would produce a "match error" along with the value you would like returned?

Comment: FWIW, you can use [regex101](http://regex101.com/) to debug your regex, though you'll have to convert them to PCRE format first (removing double escapes, and some classes Java can handle but not PCRE). Just put your string to match and regex, then click on the little bug icon on the left.

Comment: My regular expression is fine. It works as it should! The issue is that I want to know more informations in case of match errors, like for instance the index in the input string where a "bad" character was found. I'll post the full code along with a simple example.

Comment: There is no error when no match is found, there simply was no match.

Comment: @SeifeddineDridi You can still use the debug function of regex101 for that purpose :)

Comment: What about Matcher#end() returns the offset after the last character matched?

Comment: When something doesn't match, it "doesn't match" **everywhere**. Matching doesn't stop at a certain position.

Comment: Thanks for your answers...But it would be useful to signal an exception to the user like "Your string contains an invalid character at (pos)" instead of a generic message.

Answer (score 1):

There are no API methods that tell you *why* there was not match.

If you use this for any sort of (input) validation you'd have to throw a generic exception saying something like "The provided value does not match the expected pattern <put-regex-or-human-readable-pattern-here>".

Answer (score 0):

What is with this solution. It is not really nice but for my needs it worked:

```
int index = -1;
try {
     Field declaredField = Matcher.class.getDeclaredField("last");      
     declaredField.setAccessible(true); 
     index =Integer.parseInt(declaredField.get(matcher).toString()); } catch
(Exception e) { }
```